# how to get jquery substring

Tags: php

How do i get the substring `$v` of the class `rate$v`?  I can't assign `$v` as an id and do `attr('id')` because i have `$v` assigned as an id to other elements. How do i get `$v` from the class `rate$v` in jquery?

```
<?php
    foreach($v = 0; $v < 9; $v++) {
        echo "<div class='raterow'><input type='hidden' class='rate$v' value='$username' /></div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: where do you see jquery?

Comment: Oh, I answered a completely different question--couldn't really figure out what was being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to get attributes of HTML printed with PHP, in jQuery. Correct me if I'm wrong.

---

Use a `data-` attribute. It's an HTML5 feature, but all (most) browsers will keep any attributes they don't understand, so it'll work in IE6, etc.

Use [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to get that attribute and manipulate it. PHP:

```
foreach($v=0; $v<9; $v++) 
{
    echo "<div class='raterow'><input type='hidden' data-vId='$v' class='rate$v' value='$username' /></div>";
}
```

With this jQuery:

```
var foo = %('.daterow input').data('vId');
```

You can call `vId` whatever you want, providing it's prefixed with `data-`. Note that `.data()` only needs the identifier part - you can exclude `data-` from the parameter you pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<div class='raterow'><input type='hidden' class='rate" . $v . "' value='$username' /></div>";
```

Although if I were doing it I'd probably create the class name as a standalone variable and probably refactor the string concatenation to make it a bit easier to read